# Окотить рисунок — значит сделать его покошачье/покошачее

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Окотить рисунок — значит сделать его покошачье/покошачее.

Comment: сделать по-кошачьи - окошатить, хотя бы, а окотить - странная форма инфинитива от окотилась, котилась, окотиться, рождать котят о кошках.

Comment: В мире кошек все по-другому) К примеру, "кошачий" у них – качественное прилагательное, от которого можно образовать сравнительную степень.  Нам давно пора бы об этом догадаться.  С кошками жить – по-кошачьи мяукать.

Comment: Именно так! У нас форма *кошачее* для ед. ч. ср. р. приемлема, напр.: *кошачее утверждение*. (Вполне по-хорошему звучит, благозвучно.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Покошачее*. Качественное прилагательное, сравнительная степень.

Comment: Увы, прилагательного кошачее нет, а кошачий - это притяжательное прилагательное отвечающее на вопрос чей, а не какой. Так что образовать сравнительную степень качественного прилагательного таким способом не удастся, минусую)

Comment: @Буратино "у неё кошачий взгляд", считаете, это чей, а не какой? Не соглашусь

Comment: ну не соглашаться ваше право, но ИЙ - это окончание притяжательного прилагательного, у качественных прилагательных другой суффикс, не нулевой.

Comment: "Тихий", "живучий", "сладкий" вы тоже причислите к притяжательным, а не качественным, исходя из ИЙ?

Comment: Они не от названия животных и прочих названий. Тихий - от тишина, либо от тихость, у+тишить - глагола. Живучий - от жить, или жив + суффикс уч., может от живуч+есть. Сладкий от с+лад+ость.
Кошачесть - думаешь есть такое слово? Человечесть? Собачесть? Птичесть? Не думаю.

Comment: Слово "силость" тоже нет, но "посильнее" есть

Comment: Как бы там намёк на суффикс появляется

Comment: @Буратино не убедили. Ладно. закончим. Затянули слишком обсуждение

Answer (score 2):

**Все неправильно.**

Степени сравнения имеют только **качественные** имена прилагательные, так как они обозначают такой признак предмет, который может характеризоваться **разной степенью проявления**. У качественных прилагательных выделяют **сравнительную и превосходную** степени.

***Кошачий*** — притяжательное прилагательное.

Сравнить (для качественных прилаг.) : **ПОКРЕПЧЕ,** сравнит. ст. прил. и нареч. Разг. Немного крепче, более крепко. Заварить чай п. Мороз сегодня п. Выразиться п. (более резко).

Подробно о грамматике прилагательных можно прочитать **[здесь](https://studfile.net/preview/1700657/page:88/)**

Comment: Я тоже это заметил. Но мы же знаем Леопольда: ему все равно на это, он часто придумывает свои слова.

Comment: Если только так:  Окотить рисунок — значит сделать его покотоватее. Но и это авторская лексика, в словаре такого нет. Но хотя бы качественное прилагательное.

Comment: Я Леопольда не знаю, я знаю только слова, которые он пытается выдумывать. Поэтому не стоит обобщать.

Comment: Кстати, Sharon, у меня к вам один вопрос, не по теме. Почему вы ставите между числами ставите дефис, если нужно тире? Правило знаете вроде.

Comment: Как не знать, случайно, может.  Здесь многие часто дефис ставят вместо тире, вы за ними тоже приглядывайте.   Примечание. Если между двумя рядом стоящими числительными можно вставить не слова от…до, а слово или, то числительные соединяются дефисом: Пробудет в командировке пять-шесть дней (но при цифровом обозначении ставится тире: …5 — 6 дней).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Именно так! У нас форма кошачее для ед. ч. ср. р. 
 приемлема, напр.: кошачее утверждение. (Вполне по-хорошему 
 звучит, благозвучно.)
```

**О притяжательных прилагательных, которые могут переходить в качественные прилагательные**

— *У нее **кошачий** взгляд.* Суффикс ***-ИЙ***.

— *Нет у нее **кошачьего** взгляда.*  Окончание **-ЕГО.**

— *Я имею в виду, смотрит она **по-кошачьи.*** Наречие.

По смыслу (взгляд как у кошки) слово переходит в **качественное** прилагательное,  а вот грамматическая **форма** остается прежней (как у притяжательного прилагательного). Таким образом, **грамматические** возможности слова при переходе не изменились.

Поэтому никаким образом модель ***«кошачий — покошачее»***  использоваться не может, этот вариант возможен только для качественных прилагательных: **горячий — погорячее.**

**О благозвучных кошачьих словах**

Кошачее  утверждение?  Нет, есть только  **кошачье** утверждение, и никак иначе. У кошек все должно быть **кошачье.**

Все слова и формы надо **контролировать по словарям:**

**КОШАЧИЙ,** -ья, -ье. 1. к Кошка (1-2 зн.). К-ья лапа. К. мех. // **Свойственный кошке; такой, как у кошки.** К-ья повадка. К-ья ласковость. Иметь к-ьи глаза (очень зоркие). 2. Разг. Сделанный из меха кошки. К. воротник. 3. В составе некоторых зоологических и ботанических названий. К-ьи змеи. К-ьи лапки. К-ья мята. К-ья трава. Кошачий концерт (см. Концерт).

**ПО-КОШАЧЬИ**
Русский орфографический словарь: по-кошачьи

**КОШАЧЬИ**, -их; мн. Зоол. Семейство хищных млекопитающих, к которому относятся домашняя кошка, тигр, лев, рысь и др.

**ПОГОРЯЧЕЕ**
Русский орфографический словарь: погорячее